# rails attr_accessible rspec check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, shoulda, attr-accessible

When I want to test if attribute is / is not **accessible** with RSpec I'm doing it like this

```
class Foo
  attr_accesible :something_else
end

describe Foo do
  it('author should not be accessible')    {lambda{described_class.new(:author=>true)}.should raise_error ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error}
  it('something_else should be accessible'){lambda{described_class.new(:something_else=>true)}.should_not raise_error ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error}
end
```

is there better way doing that ?

...thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This is the way attribute accessibility tests are done in the Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code:attr_accessible_user_id_test), which I think are pretty good.  So, in your case, the test code could be modified slightly to read like:

```
describe Foo do
  describe "accessible attributes" do
    it "should not allow access to author" do
      expect do
        Foo.new(author: true)
      end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
    end

    it "should allow access to something_else" do
      expect do
        Foo.new(something_else: true)
      end.to_not raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
    end
  end
end
```

If this isn't what you were looking for, can you give us a better idea of what kind of solution you're after when you ask if there is a "better way"?

#### Edit

You may be interested in the [Shoulda ActiveModel matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#activemodel-matchers), which would clean up the code to just one line per test.  Something like:

```
it { should_not allow_mass_assignment_of(:author) }
it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:something_else) }
```

Comment: +1 for those shoulda matchers, I thought should don't have those two... works

Comment: This question was actually responsible for me finding out about the shoulda matchers, so thanks for asking it.  I went and refactored some of my test code to use them.

Comment: If you found the question useful, then please vote it up! The author deserves it.

Comment: @Hosam Aly, you're absolutely right, and that was an oversight on my part.  Question upvoted.